# Работа с переводчиком

Tags: android, android-studio, локализация

В Андроиде строки для разных локалей хранятся в разных файлах. А можно ли как-то эти файлы слить в один, отдать этот файл переводчику, чтобы он внес свои правки, а потом обратно разделить на разные файлы?

Фактически некий аналог Translations Editor из Android Studio, который подхватывает все файлы ресурсов, но отдельно от самой студии.

Comment: Что мешает скопировать текст для английского текста, вставить в онлайн переводчик, и скопировать перевод обратно? Или просто эти файлы отдать переводчику?

Comment: Как скопировать текст, если текст в XML разметке? Выкусывать по одной строчке? И под переводчиком я имел в виду человека.

Comment: Зачем в xml? Там должна быть просто ссылка на строковый ресурс вида @string/yourtext, а в строковосм ресурсе для русского языка будет yourtext=слово, а в английском будет yourtext=word. И переключаться всё будет автоматически при смене языка в системе

Comment: @ArtyMorris Строковые ресурсы хранятся в формате XML и речь именно об этих файлах ресурсов

Comment: Это обычный текст и он копируется, и редактируется скопом. Не понимаю в чём проблема

Comment: Щёлкните на имени строкового ресурса, и работайте с ним, как с обычным текстом

Comment: Из готовых решений есть плагин экспорта в exel: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14444-androidstringstool. В конце концов вы программист - задачка по конвертации xml во что-то другое и обратно пишется за несколько минут.